# Comparing 2 strings in If,Elif,Else loop

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement, compare

In my if/elif/else statement my program keeps returning only the else where it should be 1 B and 2 Cs.

```
document = open ("ClassNameGrades.txt","r")

content = document.read().splitlines()
As = 0
Bs = 0
Cs = 0
Ds = 0
Fs = 0

for line in content:
    split = line.split (", ")

    className = split [0]
    facultyName = split [1:1]
    studentName= split [2:2]
    grade = split [3:]

    if str(grade) == ("A"):
        As = As + 1
    elif str(grade) == ("B"):
        Bs = Bs + 1
    elif str(grade) == ("C"):
        Cs = Cs + 1
    elif str(grade) == ("D"):
        Ds = Ds + 1
    else:
        Fs = Fs + 1

print (str(As)+(" students got As."))
print (str(Bs)+(" students got Bs."))
print (str(Cs)+(" students got Cs."))
print (str(Ds)+(" students got Ds."))
print (str(Fs)+(" students got Fs."))

document.close()
```

The results for this shows as:

0 students got As.
0 students got Bs.
0 students got Cs.
0 students got Ds.
3 students got Fs.

Comment: Try `print(str(grade))` and see if it looks anything like "A" or "B" or "C" or "D".

Comment: Using `print(str(grade))` after the loop returned ['C'] as it was the last grade to be read by the file.

Comment: `['C']` isn't the same as `'C'`.

Comment: you have a bunch of syntax errors.  remove the spaces after each `split` ...and remove the parenthesis from your strings.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that was it, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are comparing a list item to a string, which is why your `if` conditions never evaluate to `True`. Instead of using the list slice notation `split[2:2]` which returns a list, you should simply fetch the items from the list using the list index notation.

```
document = open ("ClassNameGrades.txt","r")

content = document.read().splitlines()
As = 0
Bs = 0
Cs = 0
Ds = 0
Fs = 0

for line in content:

    split = line.split(", ")

    className = split[0]
    facultyName = split[1]
    studentName= split[2]
    grade = split[3]

    if str(grade) == "A":
        As = As + 1
    elif str(grade) == "B":
        Bs = Bs + 1
    elif str(grade) == "C":
        Cs = Cs + 1
    elif str(grade) == "D":
        Ds = Ds + 1
    else:
        Fs = Fs + 1

print(str(As)+(" students got As."))
print(str(Bs)+(" students got Bs."))
print(str(Cs)+(" students got Cs."))
print(str(Ds)+(" students got Ds."))
print(str(Fs)+(" students got Fs."))

document.close()
```